# JS how to set element to other coordinate after collide

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem with my "snake game" in JavaScript.
the first time a rectangle was drawn with the function which is called "drawApple" my function "collisionCheck" works fine, but when the apple is set to a another position with the function "collisionCheck" then i can not collide with my apple and its dont respawn in to a other position.
Does anyone know why?
I can't find it...

Here is the JS Code

```js
"use strict";

let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");



for (let drawSection of canvas) {
  let gamefield = drawSection.getContext("2d");
  let speed = 7;
  let snakeSpeed = 10;
  let gamerX = drawSection.width / 2;
  let gamerY = drawSection.height / 2;
  let spdX = 0;
  let spdY = 0;
  let appleX = 20;
  let appleY = 20;



  function game() {
    if (spdY < -snakeSpeed) {
      spdY = -snakeSpeed;
    } else if (spdY > snakeSpeed) {
      spdY = snakeSpeed;
    } else if (spdX > snakeSpeed) {
      spdX = snakeSpeed;
    } else if (spdX < -snakeSpeed) {
      spdX = -snakeSpeed;
    }

    screenColor();
    drawPlayer();
    drawApple();
    collisionCheck(gamerX, gamerY);
    gamerX = gamerX + spdX;
    gamerY = gamerY + spdY;
    console.log(gamerX, gamerY);


    setTimeout(game, 1000 / speed)
  }
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);

  function screenColor() {
    gamefield.fillStyle = "black";
    gamefield.fillRect(0, 0, drawSection.width, drawSection.height);
  }

  function drawPlayer() {
    gamefield.fillStyle = "purple";
    gamefield.fillRect(gamerX, gamerY, 25, 25);
  }

  function drawApple() {
    gamefield.fillStyle = "red";
    gamefield.fillRect(appleX, appleY, 25, 25);
  }

  function collisionCheck(xc, yc) {
    if (appleX == xc && appleY == yc) {
      appleX = Math.round(Math.random() * drawSection.width);
      appleY = Math.round(Math.random() * drawSection.height);
      console.log(appleX, appleY)
    }
  }


  function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
      spdY = spdY - snakeSpeed;
      spdX = spdX = 0;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
      spdY = spdY + snakeSpeed;
      spdX = spdX = 0;

    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
      spdX = spdX - snakeSpeed;
      spdY = spdY = 0;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
      spdX = spdX + snakeSpeed;
      spdY = spdY = 0;

    }
  }
  game();
}
```

```html
<canvas />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in `collisionCheck` you only set new appleX and appleY values, but you do not call `drawApple`, which I would expect you'd want to do.

```
  appleX = Math.round(Math.random() * drawSection.width);
  appleY = Math.round(Math.random() * drawSection.height);
  drawApple(); // add this
```

**Edit**: After realizing that my initial proposal was incorrect, and when I analyzed your code deeper, I realized that your condition `appleX == xc && appleY == yc` is never satisfied, given the setup of the game as it is (the speed of snake movement and the resolution of the movement being the same). If your player moved a pixel at a time, you wouldn't run into this issue, but you're skipping by 10 on each step (in the beginning of the game), so you skip the appleX/appleY point.

Comment: Thats not the solution, becouse in collisionCheck "appleX" and "appleY" get new values, and the function is called in "game" which is called itself. But thank you

Comment: Yeah, I did not get that the first time I read through. I have analyzed it a bit deeper this time, and realized that your collision check is not good enough, because your `appleX` and `appleY` are 20, 20, and your box/snake/whatever moves from 20,25 to 20,15, so the condition that `appleX == xc && appleX == yc` is never satisfied. This means that the apple will never get the new location as that if block where you randomize the new location will never be executed.

Comment: i don't understand, where is my snake change his size from 20,25 to 20,15?

Comment: No, it's not the size, it's the position that changes.

Comment: sorry, i mean the position, where do you see the change?

Comment: I have updated my answer, clarifying that the issue is with your "step resolution" or "step length"... Have a look at this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fzon8vbq/2/ and you will see that `appleX == xc && appleY == yc` never happens and cannot happen, because the y position of your snake goes from 25 to 15 when you go up, and the y position of the apple is 20, so the snake "skips" the apple position.

Comment: Ok i see. but i dont have a solution for it.

Comment: I think one problem you have is that snake speed is reused as step size, and then as your snake speeds up you will skip greater and greater lengths of the screen. Another thing I would do different is not base collisionCheck on comparison of x & y coordinates, as that's not collision. Collision is checking if the side of your snake exists in the same spot as the nearest side of your apple at a specific step in your game.